# How to hide a button in a td tag and allow it to be tabable

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want to be able to tab over hidden buttons in a table for some accessibility functions... however when I use either `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` in my CSS the td becomes not tab able.

Here is what I have so far...

html:

```
   <tbody>
      <tr tabindex="0"class="row" ng-repeat="edu in educators ">
        <td class="col">
          <div>{{edu.firstName}}</div>
          <div>{{edu.address}}</div>
        <td tabindex="1">
          <button tabindex="1" class="hidden" ng-click="moveUp(educators, edu)"></button>
        </td>
        <td tabindex="1">
          <button tabindex="1" class="hidden" ng-click="moveDown(educators, edu)"></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

css:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

both of which hide the buttons but do not allow me to tab and select my move up and down buttons

Comment: Tab works on input fields including buttons but not on table/tr/td. Since the button is not there anymore there is nothing to tab into.

Comment: this seems to work https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwJpBa

Comment: this method does not work